# How can I unbind a child panel from its parent panel?

Tags: .net, winforms, panel, parent-child

How can I make a panel visible which is inside another panel whose visible property is set to false?

I am using Windows Forms.

Comment: Beyond it being impossible, I'm not really sure how it even makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, hard Windows rule.  Just don't make the parent of the panel you want to show the panel you want to hide.  It should be parented to the form instead.  The designer doesn't make that easy, you'll have to move it to the right spot after the InitializeComponent() call.